# MMSE of X given PDF

Tags: signal-analysis

"Suppose RVs $X$ and $Y$ with probability distribution functions $F_X$, $F_Y$, and $F_{XY}$. Find a linear estimate $\hat{x}$ of $X$ by the observed $Y$ such that $\hat{x}$ correspond to the minimum mean square error of the linear estimator."

This is the question I am to solve, but I have no idea how to do it. I was thinking maybe you should calculate the expectation of the error, but not sure how that would work. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: are these $F_{(\cdot)}$ functions probability **distribution** functions or probability **density** functions?  the latter is the derivative of the former.

Comment: also looks like a better place for this is the math SE.

Answer (score 1):

Let me summarize the results of the **linear mean square error estimator** (LMSEE) of a r.v. Y from the observed r.v. X, with their individual and joint pdfs $f_X(x),f_Y(y),f_{XY}(x,y)$ respectively.

Considering that $$\hat{Y} = a X + b$$ is a linear estimator of $Y$ from $X$. It can be shown that the optimal values of $a$ and $b$ that would minimze the expected value of the squared estimation error $$ \mathcal{E} = E \{ (Y-\hat{Y})^2 \} $$
is given by:

$$ 
\begin{cases} 
a &= \frac{\sigma_Y}{\sigma_X} \cdot \rho_{XY} \\
b &= \mu_Y - a \cdot  \mu_X
\end{cases}
$$

Hence the **linear** MMSE estimator of Y is:
$$\boxed{  \hat{Y} = \frac{\sigma_Y}{\sigma_X} \rho_{XY} (X-\mu_X) + \mu_Y }$$ 
And the minimum mean squared error is found to be:
$$ \mathcal{E} = \sigma_Y^2 (1 - \rho_{XY}^2) $$

Where, $\mu_X,\mu_Y, \sigma_X, \sigma_Y, \rho_{XY}$ are mean of $X$, mean of $Y$, std dev of $X$, std.dev. of $Y$ and correlation coefficient between $X$ and $Y$ which is $\rho_{XY} = \frac{\text{cov}(X,Y)}{\sigma_X \sigma_Y } =\frac{E\{(X-\mu_X)(Y-\mu_Y)\}}{\sigma_X \sigma_Y } $ .

Note that for all RVs the optimal MMSE estimator is the conditional expectation $\hat{Y} = E\{Y \mid X\}$ which is, in general, a nonlinear estimator. However for jointly Gaussian RVs, the optimal MMSE estimator, $E\{Y \mid X\}$  becomes a linear function of $X$ (the Linear MMSEE) and is given by the equation above.

Comment: Your choice of notation is bass ackwards from that used by the OP. Also, for _all_ random variables, the optimal MMSE estimator is $E[Y\mid X]$, and it just so happens that for jointly Gaussian random variables, the MMSE estimator is a linear function that coincides with the optimal linear MMSE estimator (it better coincide, right?).

Comment: @DilipSarwate Yes I have delibaretely used the backwards notation; i.e., estimator of Y from X. I assume OP can (should) convert it into X from Y form, simply by replacing X with Y :-) For my last (bonus) paragraph, paraphrasing it like you did is better; i.e., the conditional expectation is the optimal MMSE for all RV and for jointly Gaussian RVs the conditional expectation becomes a (mathematically) linear function of X whereas for (all) other distributions it is nonlinear.

Comment: @Fat32: I didn't know you were a stat guy also. Not that it matters but, in statistics, that's often referred to as the gauss-markov theorem. namely, that out of all linear estimators, the one you derived is the MMSE. do you do physics also !!!!!!

Comment: @markleeds mmm I could probably not be considered as a stat guy! :-) However EE DSP includes a must have statistical signal processing portfolio in the graduate courseware...

Comment: @fat32: Got it. Unfortunately for me,  statistics  didn't have  a signal processing for statisticians portfolio in the graduate courseware.

Comment: Fat32, “for all other distributions it is nonlinear” is not true. For example, if $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed on the interior of the triangle with vertices at (0,0), (1,0), and (1,1), then $E[Y \mid X]$ is a linear function.

Comment: @DilipSarwate ok thanks let me correct it. it's already stating that *in general nonlinear* I hope this is ok now...